# How to create a Simulink bus from a typedef struct defined in a C .h file?

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

Is there a way to create a Simulink bus from the definition of a C struct? Let's say I have some C struct definition in a header file:

```
typedef struct {
  double a, b;
} u_T;
```

Can I use this to automatically generate a `Simulink.Bus` object?

**Edit:** Is there a tool that generates `Matlab` code for creating `Simulink.Bus` objects describing the structs from a `.h` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import a header when creating a bus object, but this is only used for code generation with Simulink Coder, not for normal simulation with Simulink.  See the documentation on [`Simulink.Bus`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/simulink.bus.html) for more details.

The only way to do what you want would be to write a parser that reads your .h file and creates a bus object in the MATLAB workspace. I don't know of any such tool I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I want such a parser. I know the code generation thing but I already have the .h file (because I write C S-functions - I don't generate them) and I need the opposite of what Simulink's code generation does.

Comment: I guess I'll define all bus structures in Simulink's bus editor and generate a .h file via code generation for my C S-functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is supported in the latest version of MATLAB (2017a). Use the following command.

```
importInfo = Simulink.importExternalCTypes(headerFiles)
```

For more info see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.importexternalctypes.html